# CQWP or default list view webpart

Tags: list-view, content-query-web-part, object-cache, output-cache

I have bunch of document libraries for Sales site collection. These doc libs are by Year. These are going to be read only records. By default the list view displays everything. No filter needs to be applied when user opens a document library.

Will I be adding any benefits if I delete the built in lvwp and add cqwp? I do have one managed-metadata for navigation.

or Should I leave the built in list view and configure cache (Not sure which cache I have to configure. I am assuming site collection object cache and/or output cache). These are high level sales analysis type items. Maximum a doc lib has 50,000 records. Some libraries has only 20+k records.

Please suggest as how can I make the navigation super fast for end user. (again, these are going to be read only data. so I will add users to the visitor group). Please suggest.

Comment: http://www.spwp.net/web-parts/item-lister-web-part.aspx not an option unless it's a built in WP. I setup the "object cache" to improve item rendering. The site collection is based on Document Center so I dont get the other 2 cache settings in the site collection menu. I did not see any changes as far as page load concern. I saw same about half a second to load the document libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can gain any significant performance by switching the webpart type.

Possibly the only way would be to build a custom asp.net web part that hooks into the doc libs and displays the data in a repeater.

But that obviously would require development.

You could also follow some guidelines in order to maintain your current/future lists properly:
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=162

All the best.

KS

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: These are pretty large lists. I would review this post: http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/10/27/working-with-large-lists-in-sharepoint-2010-list-throttling.aspx

You can configure output caching from the web.config file. Look for the section titled: To configure page output cache profile settings, here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770229(office.14).aspx

---

Object Cache is more around navigation and cross list queries. It doesn't sound like it's going to help with this particular issue.

Output cache is what you are looking for. It will cache the page and should improve performance.

You could use the CQWP and object cache to accomplish what you want, but normally CQWP is used to aggregate content over multiple lists and libraries and to present this content to the user in a single, unified view. With that in mind it would be best to stick with the default list view and enable output caching.